# need to fetch individual field values based on the position specified by the user from a variable not an array

Tags: perl

I need to get the fields from a line based on numbers , where the fields are separated by spaces. Now the problem is that the fields may themselves contain spaces but they would be in a single quote.

Ie:

```
$var="1 'abc def' 234 '' '456' 77 'ghi jkl mno p ' 99 ' q ' 88 ' r'";
```

How do I fetch `abc def`, when user wants element at position 1?

Comment: Tricky. I would probably check if the fitst letter is a single Quote. Then i would `split(/'/, $var);` and depending on wether the first letter was a Quote, either the ones with even or with odd index are the quoted elements while the others have to be further splitted at spaces. And reinserted at their original Position...

Comment: Oh, just had a better idea. How about you first split at spaces and then iterate through the elements, checking wether they contain a singlequote, merging those elements with the next elements until you reach another element with a Quote? Might work if the Input does not have fields like '' or 'abc' allthough such cases could certainly be treated individually.

Comment: the string is inconsistent
l

Comment: the thing has to be done on around 10 million records 10 million lines
so it takes forever in this case

Comment: What do you mean by inconsistent? Also, you will Need to either convert Input into an Array or iterate through the fields on each call either way. If Speed is such an issue, Perl might not be your best bet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check [**Text::ParseWords**](http://perldoc.perl.org/Text/ParseWords.html) core module,

```
use Text::ParseWords;
my $var = "1 'abc def' 234 '' '456' 77 'ghi jkl mno p ' 99 ' q ' 88 ' r'";
my @words = quotewords('\s+', 0, $var);

# use Data::Dumper; print Dumper \@words;
my $position = 1;
print $words[$position]; # 'abc def'
```

Comment: Text::ParseWords looks really nice!

Comment: That is a nice module, really learned something usefull today.

Comment: Text::ParseWords is actually really nice.thanks for the help.even I  learned something new today

Answer (score 1):

my (untested) approach would be

```
use Data::Dumper;

my $var="1 'abc def' 234 '' '456' 77 'ghi jkl mno p ' 99 ' q ' 88 ' r'";

my @data = split("\s",$var);
my @result;

foreach my $substr (@data) {
    s/[\"|\']//g;
    push(@result,$_) unless $_ eq "";
}

print Dumper @data;
```

will return something like this

```
@data = [
    "1",
    "abc def",
    "234",
    ...
];
```

now you can access each object simply by

```
$data[index];
```